# Retrieving a cast array in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, casting

Hi I think I'm misunderstanding casts? Basically I am trying to display an already stored array back to my view and its not working, i have already stored the arrays and im just trying to retrieve them into plain text

I have a table:

```
> Games
>>id |
>>name |
>>mode
```

MyController.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Game;
    use App\Mode;
    
    class MyController extends Controller
    {
      

      public function gameView($id)
        {
            $game = Game::find($id);
            return view('admin.game.view', ['game' => $game]);
            
        }   
    }
```

My model Game.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Game extends Model
    {
    
        protected $casts = [
            'mode' => 'array',
        ];

        public function modes()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Mode::class);
        }

    }
```

Finally my View view.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">View User's Teams & Manage</div>
    
                    <div class="panel-body">
                       <ul>
                            <li>{{$game->name}}</li>
                            <li>{{$game->mode}}</li>
                            <li>{{$game->size}}</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: Why are you casting it to an object/array and then trying to echo it like a string?

Comment: i have it the entry stored as an array in my database, and im trying to echo unserialize the array so it shows it in a readable format

Comment: Ok but if you have an array, you can't just echo it. Does this code make sense? `$foo = [1, 4, 5, 8]; echo $foo;` No, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways of printing an array, however, the simplest method is using the foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($game->mode as $mode)
    <span>{{ $mode }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Or you can do something like `{{ implode(", ", $game->mode) }}` depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the array like a string and there is the problem so you need to loop for the array of mode.

```
@for($i=0;$i<count($game->mode);$i++){ // here you print your result }
```